# bash can't find git command: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, git, bash

I've been using git along with a project in order to have version control for quite some time now. But all of a sudden, it stopped working! I noticed that while pushing new changes, because I received this message:

```
/home/user/bin/git/bin/git: No such file or directory
```

Also, whereis command is unable to find where the program named git is present:

```
> whereis git
git:
```

Any idea on how I can solve this?

Comment: can you share output of `ls -l $(which git)`.?

Comment: Please locate git binary and add the path to it in your `PATH` variable in `~/.bashrc` file, something like `export PATH=<git PATH>:$PATH` This would work unless you have lost your git binary :)

Comment: why would git be expected in a directory like /home/user/bin/git/bin/? why can't you use the git as supplied by the linux distribution you're using, which definitely will not install git into /home/user/bin/git/bin/ unless you explicitely asked it to.

Comment: @Jayesh I am not allowed to share that output, but it's quite a big one. It starts with "which: no git in (...)" which might be revealing enough.

Comment: @Jord in that file there's this line: 

export PATH=$PATH:/home/user/bin/git/bin

I tried this command: export PATH=</home/user/bin/git/bin>:$PATH with no luck! Isn't it the same as having that command in the file you mentioned? Nonetheless, the output is shown below:

bash: /home/user/bin/git/bin: No such file or directory

Does this mean I lost my git binary? This is impossible...

Comment: Can you share the output of: find / -name git | xargs ls -ld

Comment: @Bushmills I found that strange myself, but I've been unable to spot the git location in my machine. I'm using suse btw!

Comment: @Gaurav I'm not able to run that command, because I don't have root access. Without root access I just receive "permission denied"

Comment: you can use package manager to query files in packages - or you can use "which" to see directory from which an executable will be executed. if which gives no output, most likely git hasn't been installed

Comment: @Bushmills To use package manager I would have to have root access, which I don't. I tried the command "which git", and the output goes like this: which: no git in (...)"

I'm not allowed to disclose the remainder of the output (which is quite big), but from my understanding, which wasn't able to find git binaries in any of the defined directory paths.

Comment: no root could explain why git was installed in user dir. easiest would probably be to ask your admin to install it for you. from package repository of distribution, this requires very little effort.

Comment: It turns that my admin actually removed git accidentally... The problem is now solved! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have a dead link to a local version of git (which you might have removed?)  in your $PATH. Try `which git` or `find / -lname /home/user/bin/git/bin/git` to spot it.

Comment: As I commented in the initial post comments, the command which git doesn't help! Its output starts with "which: no git in (...)", and I'm not allowed to share the rest. It is quite big though! And I don't have permission to run the other command you gave me....

Comment: 1. How do you invoke git to get the error in your question?
2. the second command tries to search the whole file system. Ofcourse you are likely not allowed to acces all folders, just dicard errors as in `find / -lname /home/user/bin/git/bin/git 2>/dev/null`

Comment: 1. All git commands ("git log", "git status") produce the following error: "bash: /home/user/bin/git/bin/git: No such file or directory". 2. This command produces no output at all...

Comment: a different thought just occurred to me, did you check that there is no symbolic broken link at /home/user/bin/git/bin/git or, guessing from the weierd path, at /home/user/bin/git ? i.e. could you `find /home/user/bin/ -iname "git"` and check wether the results are symbolic links to no longer existing files? I would recommend to just delete your whole local version of git `rm -rf /home/user/bin/git` and ask your admin to install the package, anyway.

Comment: It turns that my admin actually removed git accidentally... The problem is now solved! Thanks for your help!